# How to specify a description using cardano-cli

Tags: transaction

In cardano-cli, when I create a transaction file (.body and also .signed) the contents of the file appear to be in JSON format with 3 fields, as follows

```
{
    "type": "Tx AlonzoEra",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "84a4008282582066188ffe......
```

I have searched the full cardano-cli help and done multiple Internet searches, but I cannot see how I can or should use that "description" field. I'm envisioning simple plain text such as "for new account jwb". Of course that can be put into metadata, which may be best anyway. Perhaps the description field is meant to be manually or programmatically changed, if desired, before or after submission, like a post-it note memo?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to currently specify the description via cardano-cli. Some things are generated with a default description and others are not. You can modify the description as it has no bearing on serialization.